# How can i find the divisors of an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a program that takes an integer N as input and prints out (on a
>   single line) all the divisors of N. Input validation: If N is a
>   negative number (strictly smaller than zero), your program should
>   display an error message and keep asking for a valid N (see sample run
>   below).
>
> Sample run:

```
 Enter N: 10
 The divisors of N are: 1 2 5 10
```

i know how to input everything, im just stuck on how to do the divisor part. would i use a nested loop of some sort or could i use a sum_math type thing?

Comment: Also, you should probably post some code, what have you tried so far?  What is working?  Can you at least show us that you are reading in numbers and determining if they are positive or negative.

Comment: @jgritty: The homework tag has been deprecated. So apparently it doesn't matter if it's homework any more...

Answer (score 0):

This task sounds like homework. That is why the solution I will propose does not use any built-in functions.

In order to find all the divisors of a given number n you should iterate over all the numbers up to sqrt(N) and if the given number `i` divides n(i.e. `n%i == 0`) you should add the number `i` and `(n/i)` to the divisors. After that sort the array. Take special care if n is perfect square(then `i` and `n/i` are the same thing).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Minor complaint: The sqrt(N) trick is vital when you get dangerous, but overkill for homework, where performance doesn't matter and you don't want to burden yourself with verifying it's in fact correct (as you should always do!).